# USB UART Bridge with capability of handling fast charge VBus

Tags: usb, uart, charger

I am trying to design a charging circuit which support QuickCharge but also I want to add USB-UART bridge to communicate with on board MCU. 
How can I establish voltage level safe communication through UART bridge while VBus level is controlled by fast charge IC? What I mean, VBus would be get higher as 20V. Generally found USB-UART bridges are just handling 5V max. 
Lets look CP2102. This IC has actually self-powered configuration through Vdd but that still needs to be connected to VBus with threshold 5V.
There should be some simple solution I could not think.

Comment: The simple solution may very well be to not mix fast charger capability with a USB comms capability. It would seem that your not being sure of how to handle the situation suggests that you should leave well enough alone.

Comment: Would a 5-V voltage regulator work for you? What kind of reference designs are available from QC control ICs manufacturers to guide you?

Comment: only 3.3V is needed for the UART beridge, perhaps there's an LDO regulator that can handle 20V in

Comment: what sort of USB-UART bridge is capable of also negotiating fast charge?

Comment: @Jasen, USB-UART bridges don't negotiate QuickCharge, true, but power circuits around it can. However, there seems to be one little problem with QC: it uses DC levels on USB data lines to negotiate fast charge, and gets disabled if you need to use USB for data transfer. I have found no indication that QC and data sync can work simultaneously. I would be glad to hear otherwise.

Comment: I am doing something similar.  It is difficult to separate the D+/D- from the charging circuit because in USB2.0 those are used to set charging limits. Quick charge may use those and a combination of other things. Also, the ADP protocol will play with the VBus voltage to ensure the connection is still there. So you cant just run your data lines to component A and run your power to component B.

In the end you will either have to formulate a type of Quick Charge hub or you can implement a Charge Through Device. Unfortunately I am working on USBC PD charging so I can't point you to 2.0Stuff

Answer (score 1):

You should use a USB 3 PD controller (sink role). These devices pass the D+ and D- while implementing the power levels negotiations with the host.

Answer (score 0):

power the UART from the battery.

Comment: how is it not a solution?

Comment: Sorry my mistake; deleted the automatic remark.

Comment: Would it be a problem to connect all data lines then? USB-UART Bridge would be CP2102 and quick charge IC is CHY103D.

Comment: CHY103 goes inside the charger, what do you have inside the device to call for fast charge?

Comment: CHY103 makes it fast charger by communicating with the connected device through data lines. Voltage feedback network is controlled by it.

Comment: but yes, best solution could be the powering uart bridge from circuit side. i will give it a try and write result after prototype

Comment: @meakcey, The CHY103 is a **charger-side** IC, it PROVIDES switching to fast charging modes. What is your DEVICE_SIDE IC? The one that initiates the QC protocol?